# how can we iterate in ArrayList inside HashMap?

Tags: arraylist, hashmap

I want to print each value in ArrayList separately
i.e {1=[A, B,C, D], 2=[E, F, G, H]}

HashMap> hash=new HashMap>();
// Now i wnat to travesr inside array list of specific key in HashMap

if user enter 1 (i.e Key) then output should be
A
B
C
D

if user enter 2 (i.e Key) then output should be
E
F
G
H

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, I get your question, but if you want to traverse an array of keys and look up all the values corresponding to these keys in a hashmap, you could do something like this (assuming the question is in java):

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
  public static HashMap<Integer, String[]> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, String[]>();
  public static int[] arrToTraverse = {1,2};

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] s1 = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
    String[] s2 = {"E", "F", "G", "H"};
    hmap.put(1, s1);
    hmap.put(2, s2);
    for(int no : arrToTraverse) {
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getValue(no)));
    }
  }

  public static String[] getValue(int key) {
    return hmap.get(key); 
  }
}
```

Which will output:

```
[A, B, C, D]
[E, F, G, H]
```